# Cannot determine project or target for Architect command Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

```
C:\Users\muhiuddin.TOWERTECH\test\testapp>ng build --target=production
```

or

```
C:\Users\muhiuddin.TOWERTECH\test\testapp>ng run
```

When I run a new project  or build it give me "Cannot determine project or target for Architect command" error. I am new to Angular. Kindly give me easy solution.

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 9.3.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.0.7
```

```
>Cannot determine project or target for Architect command.
Error: Cannot determine project or target for Architect command.
    at MergeMapSubscriber._loadWorkspaceAndArchitect.pipe.operators_1.concatMap [as project] (C:\Users\muhiuddin.TOWERTECH\test\testapp\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:62:27)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (C:\Users\muhiuddin.TOWERTECH\test\testapp\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:65:27)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (C:\Users\muhiuddin.TOWERTECH\test\testapp\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:55:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\Users\muhiuddin.TOWERTECH\test\testapp\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:64:18)
    at TapSubscriber._next (C:\Users\muhiuddin.TOWERTECH\test\testapp\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\tap.js:62:26)
    at TapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\Users\muhiuddin.TOWERTECH\test\testapp\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:64:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (C:\Users\muhiuddin.TOWERTECH\test\testapp\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:84:26)
    at InnerSubscriber._next (C:\Users\muhiuddin.TOWERTECH\test\testapp\node_modules\rxjs\internal\InnerSubscriber.js:25:21)
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\Users\muhiuddin.TOWERTECH\test\testapp\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:64:18)
    at MapSubscriber._next (C:\Users\muhiuddin.TOWERTECH\test\testapp\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\map.js:52:26)
```

Comment: Look at the ng (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki) CLI Wiki.  `ng run` is like _execute_ something, not _run my app_.  `ng serve` or `ng run <appname>:serve` seems like what you were trying.  Some syntax changed a little in 6.

Answer (score 32):

Use:

```
ng serve
```

See angular CLI docs - https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki

Comment: Btw 'ng serve' is to run a dev server, but npm run build is to compile and publish a build.

Comment: Yeah that's right, the ```ng serve -o``` really saves, but depends on project configurations. ```npm start``` can work as well.

Answer (score 22):

Double check command line syntax. This error can show if `ng` used instead of `npm` like when using package.json shortcut scripts.

```
npm run debug   (Good)
ng run debug    (Bad)
```

Comment: Good Catch! It gets confusing sometimes. ;)

Comment: Thank you very much! this one got me.

Comment: What are the options other than `debug`?

Comment: @justin.m.chase programmer choice. `start` is a common one. For example my `package.json` has `"scripts": { "start": "ng serve --host my.website.com --port 443 -o" }`. So typing `npm run start` is simply saying "run my 'start' script".

Comment: Thanks a lot, good i've found your answer first

Comment: @TinySkillz glad to hear it, be sure to upvote the answer!

Answer (score 7):

Check out the cli [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build).

I believe you need to specify your project's name in the build command.

`ng build [project]`

Also you can do the production build with the following command.

`ng build [project] --prod`

Comment: thanks both your example working fine now. But i still get same error on run. eg "ng run [project]"

Comment: @MUHIUDDIN There is an issue on github in the angular-cli repo about not showing enough information to the user about this very same error message. Check it out: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10955

Comment: @MUHIUDDIN for the `run` command try this: ng run needs a target in the format of project:target and is erroring out because of that.

Answer (score 7):

had this after upgrading to angular 6.

appears like the CLI command has changed to :

```
ng build --configuration <environment-name>
```

the migration from 5 to 6 also created a new "angular.json" file which now contains all the different configurations and their names.

Answer (score 1):

Update `angular.json` file. Add `defaultProject` property (value will be the name of the desired project)

Answer (score 0):

In Angular version 6, the build command is changed. 
Changing  `"build": "ng build --target=production --aot=true"` to `"build": "ng build --prod --aot"` in package.json worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem after cloning the project from my repository on another machine.
I used the commands:

```
$ npm link

$ ng serve
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem after update the project from main branch.

I used the command: `npm install`

## If node requires a minimum Node.js version >= v14.15.

```
sudo npm cache clean -f /
sudo npm install -g n /
sudo n stable /
```

## For changing node versions

```
nvm install v16.10.         # Install v16.10.
nvm use v16.10.             # Use v16.10.
```