# Cannot determine project or target for Architect command angular4

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm trying to run the following command: `ng build --target=production --base-href /`
but it gives me the following error:

> Error: Cannot determine project or target for Architect command.
>       at MergeMapSubscriber._loadWorkspaceAndArchitect.pipe.operators_1.concatMap
>   [as project]
>   (C:\training\angular4\angular-reddit\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:70:27)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (C:\training\angular4\angular-reddit\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:65:27)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber._next (C:\training\angular4\angular-reddit\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:55:18)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\training\angular4\angular-reddit\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:64:18)
>       at TapSubscriber._next (C:\training\angular4\angular-reddit\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\tap.js:62:26)
>       at TapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\training\angular4\angular-reddit\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:64:18)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (C:\training\angular4\angular-reddit\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:84:26)
>       at InnerSubscriber._next (C:\training\angular4\angular-reddit\node_modules\rxjs\internal\InnerSubscriber.js:25:21)
>       at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\training\angular4\angular-reddit\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:64:18)
>       at MapSubscriber._next (C:\training\angular4\angular-reddit\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\map.js:52:26)

I'm New to Angular. Can anyone help me?

Comment: checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51221135/cannot-determine-project-or-target-for-architect-command-angular this link

Comment: @AniketAvhad i try that answer but it give me another error, This Error : "Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found.
Error: Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found." but angular.json file is already in that folder

Comment: try "ng build --prod base-href /" this command also target the production

Comment: @AniketAvhad "Project 'base-href' could not be found in workspace.
Error: Project 'base-href' could not be found in workspace."

Comment: If you are using angular 6 then you have to use...'ng build --configuration=production --base-href /'

Comment: @AniketAvhad **Thank you :) Problem solved ** :)

Comment: is my solution worked for you..?

Comment: If my solution working for you then accept the answer so other can get help from this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In angular 6 version **--target** replace with **--configuration** or **-c**

use below command,

`ng build --configuration=production --base-href /`

OR

`ng build --c=production --base-href /`